# Вывод значений массива (множественное свойство)

Tags: битрикс, интернет-магазин

Есть у меня свойство `PRODUCTS_ASSORTIMENT` в нем находятся id товаров.

Например 12404 и 12405.

Присвоил переменной свои данные.

```
$arrMyTer[] = Array($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["PRODUCTS_ASSORTIMENT"]["~VALUE"]);
```

После вывожу данные!

```
print_r($arrMyTer);
```

Вот что получилось

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 12404 [1] => 12405 ) ) )
```

Дальше у меня есть фильтр ( для вывода товаров по ID)

```
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>16, "ID"=>$arrMyTer, "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
```

Но значения не выводятся.

Если взять прописать так то отображает товары!

```
 $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>16, "ID"=>Array(12404,12405), "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
```

или просто

```
$myMy = 12404;
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>16, "ID"=>$myMy, "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
```

> Как правильно получить данные с
>   `Array($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["PRODUCTS_ASSORTIMENT"]["~VALUE"]);`
>   что бы отображались товары!

или как получить такой результат,

```
Array ( [0] => 12404 [1] => 12405 )
```

я так понимаю если будет массив в таком видео то id успешно прилетит!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы плодите слишком много вложенных массивов. Зачем? Приведите ID в $arFilter к такому виду:

```
"ID" => $arResult["PROPERTIES"]["PRODUCTS_ASSORTIMENT"]["~VALUE"],
```

и все получится

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри мой код, скорее всего это то, что Вам нужно:

```
$arrMyTer = array([(["12404 ","12405 "])]);

//print_r($arrMyTer);

foreach($arrMyTer as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1){
        print_r($value1);
    }
}
```